# Resizing a JScrollPane based on window size

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, miglayout

After much searching, I hope this will bring me an answer.

Ok, I have a JFrame, which has a a JPanel across the top, and one across the bottom. It also has one on the side, which contains a JScrollPane. The top and bottom panels should remain a consistent size with the window resizing, but the side panel should change vertically. Unfortunately, no scrollbar shows up at all when the JScrollPane has too many items. Rather, the entire window is enlarged, pushing the bottom panel and all excess within the JScrollPane off-screen.

I have been using MigLayout, but if I need to use another layout for the side panel I can. Here is my most recent **failed** iteration of code.

This is where I add the JScrollPane:

```
public MenuPanel(){
    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    innerPanel = new InnerPanel();
    jsp = new JScrollPane(innerPanel, 
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED, 
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    this.add(jsp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}
```

This is inside the main window:

```
private void addSideSelectionPane() {
    side = new SelectionPanel();
    this.add(side, "wmax 200, growy");
}
```

And here is the code where I create the main window:

```
public InsWindow(){
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setExtendedState( this.getExtendedState()| java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
    this.setLayout(new MigLayout("debug, nogrid, fill", "[grow, fill]", "[pref!]10[grow, fill]"));
    this.addTestLabel();
    this.addSideSelectionPane();
    this.addMainWindow();
    this.addBottomPanel();
    this.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: Nobody can guess what happens because you posted kind of random code snippets. Add SSCCE please.